# intuit merchant services with opensource shopping cart

Tags: payment-gateway, intuit-partner-platform

Has anyone been able to integrate intuit's merchant services with any of the following shopping carts?

- Magento
- Zencart
- osCommerce
- virtuemart
- oscMAX

I am setting up a shopping cart site for a client and they want to use intuit merchant services. They also use Fishbowl inventory(also intuit). I wanted to ask and see if anyone has accomplished this (not buy purchasing integration software) and what the necessary steps would be. Would this require building my own intuit app using the api/sdk and shopping cart module?

Answer (score 1):

I've done this for every shopping cart you listed above.

You will obviously have to do some coding- you'll have to write a gateway module for whatever shopping cart you're using. However, if you use the [QuickBooks PHP DevKit](https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=56&threadid=13858&forumid=1), that should be pretty trivial to do. The actual QuickBooks Merchant Services specific code is as simple as:

```
// Create an instance of the MerchantService object 
$MS = new QuickBooks_MerchantService(
    $dsn, 
    $path_to_private_key_and_certificate, 
    $application_login,
    $connection_ticket);

// Create the CreditCard object
$Card = new QuickBooks_MerchantService_CreditCard($name, $number, $expyear, $expmonth, $address, $postalcode, $cvv);

// We're going to authorize $295.00
$amount = 295.0;

if ($Transaction = $MS->authorize($Card, $amount))
{
   ... do something here ...
}
```

If you want to dive in to the more technical bits of it, you should refer to the QuickBooks Merchant Services documentation on Intuit's website:
[QuickBooks Merchant Services documentation](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0085_QuickBooks_Windows_SDK/qbms/0060_Documentation/Sending_Requests)

We also have some additional PHP-specific information about QuickBooks Merchant Services on our website:
[PHP + QuickBooks Merchant Services](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_qbms_integration)

If you get stuck/need help, contact me with the info in my profile- we have pre-built plugins for almost all of those shopping carts that we sell and support commercially.